# Show that $A=B$, provided that $A^2=B^2$ (and some other conditions are satisfied)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to do this question from an old past paper, no answers to look at and because it's from a previous year I'm not entirely sure I've even covered the material; here it is:

> Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be such that $A^2 = B^2,\, AB = BA$ and $\det(A + B) \ne 0$. Show that $A = B$.

I've been playing around with it for ages but can't get anything, from the determinant part I'm guessing I have to involve the extant inverse of $A+B$ but I've never done that before and from looking it up it seems abit beyond what I should be doing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: Expand and simplify $(A-B)(A+B) = A^2 + AB - BA - B^2 = \cdots$

If you can show that $(A-B)(A+B) = 0$, then you can multiply both sides by $(A+B)^{-1}$. (The inverse of $A+B$ exists since $\det(A+B) \neq 0$.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a direct proof:
\begin{align*}
A&=(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)A\\
&=(A+B)^{-1}(A^2+BA)\\
&=(A+B)^{-1}(B^2+AB)\\
&=(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)B=B
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

When $n=1$, this is immediate since $A$ and $B$ are nothing but real numbers:
$$
0=A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B)\tag{1}
$$
and $\det(A+B)\neq 0$ means $A+B\neq 0$ which allows one to *cancel* the $A+B$ term.

For $n>1$, (1) is no true in general since matrices do not necessarily commute. But in this particular problem, one has $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 0):

we have ,  $\det(A+B)\neq0 \implies (A+B)$ is non-singular matrix.

Now,

$(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2=A^2-B^2=O$  ( since, $AB=BA$ and $A^2=B^2 $ )

you should know that ,

> If the product of two matrices is null , then either both will be
>   singular or one of them must be null itself.

Therefore $A-B=O\implies A=B$ .
Hope it may helpful!